# Remake code fail

Tags: javascript, html, css

I tried to do this exactly but it doesn't work...

http://jsfiddle.net/F4BmP/2604/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head> 
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="website.css">
<script src="website.js"></script>
</head>

<body> 
<div class="menu">Menu</div>
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />(Bottom!)

</body>


</html>
```

//website.css

```
.menu {
    background:#345;
    color:#FFF;
    height:2em;
    padding:.5em;
    position:absolute;
    top:50px;
    width:100%;
}
.fixed {
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
}
```

//website.js

```
/* Dynamic top menu positioning
 *
 */

var num = 50; //number of pixels before modifying styles

$(window).bind('scroll', function () {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > num) {
        $('.menu').addClass('fixed');
    } else {
        $('.menu').removeClass('fixed');
    }
});

//USE SCROLL WHEEL FOR THIS FIDDLE DEMO
```

Why doesn't this work when I open this html file?
I like to make that kind of navigation bar.
Who can help me?

Comment: Your JSFiddle demo appears to be working fine.

Comment: You need to include jQuery lib which jsfiddle demo uses it... see the left column

Comment: @JamesDonnelly *I tried to do this exactly but it doesn't work...* so he says that it doesn't work for him on his local, he provided jsfiddle link for referencing the code he is using

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not include a reference to jQuery in your HTML, that is why it is not working.

Add the following before your website.js script tag in the head.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="website.js"></script>
```

Comment: I did and I also give the person the answer since they need to know what their issue is. Just closing it does not help.

Comment: Yes, it does. Because now he knows that he'll get an answer, regardless of how crappy or under researched his question was, even if it gets closed.

Comment: @epascarello great, that settles up...

Comment: Still not working...

Comment: Ah, you are loading it from a file and not a local server. You need to change the url to start with http://... Updated the url in the answer.

Comment: It is not working because you did not follow directions. Add it BEFORE the script tag in the head, you added it after.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add this line to your HTML, in your `<head>` tag, before your other `<script>` tag

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```